# Template specialization syntax error? Not sure

Tags: c++, templates

I'm having a bit of trouble getting this template specialization working. I'm new to the topic, so the possibility I have totally butchered this is entirely possible.

I got the general template working just fine, but upon trying to make the specification for int, I keep getting an error "Out-of-line definition of 'Matrix' does not match any declaration in Matrix int>.

Now, I think that they match, but obviously something must be wrong. What say you gurus? Also, not to be rude, but the 'you should actually just use X from the STL' comments won't be of much help, I've got to figure this out for an assignment. Cheers!

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{    
public:
    Matrix(int vert, int edge);
    ~Matrix();
    T* & operator[](int index);
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&);
    Matrix<T> operator*(Matrix<T>);
    int numVerticies();
    int numEdges();
private:
    T** matrix;
    int verticies;
    int edges;
    const int summation(T** mat1, int, Matrix<int> mat2, int, int verts);
};

template<>
class Matrix<int>
{
public:
    Matrix(int vert, int edge);
    ~Matrix();
    int*& operator[](int index);
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&);
    Matrix<int> operator*(Matrix<int>);
    int numVerticies();
    int numEdges();
private:
    int** matrix;
    int verticies;
    int edges;
    const int summation(int** mat1, int, Matrix<int> mat2, int, int verts);
};
```

Brought in with other members using inclusion method:

```
template<int>
Matrix<int>::Matrix(int vert, int edge)
{
    matrix = new int* [vert];

    for (int i=0; i<vert; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new int[vert];
    }

    verticies = vert;
    edges = edge;

    for (int i=0; i<vert; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<vert; j++) {
            matrix[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `T**` is possibly one of the worst ways to write a matrix. Any reason why you are not using a proper linear algebra library like uBlas or NT2?

Comment: Please perfectly quote all errors you get in your compile.  Please include what line the error occurs at in your sample code.  Eliminate irrelevant code and post a http://sscce.org/ -- I'll bet dollars to donuts that `numVerticies` has *nothing* to do with your problem, so delete it before posting.  And before posting, make sure your problem still occurs in your posted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just avoid using the `template<>` prefix:

```
Matrix<int>::Matrix(int vert, int edge)
{
    matrix = new int* [vert];

    for (int i=0; i<vert; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new int[vert];
    }

    verticies = vert;
    edges = edge;

    for (int i=0; i<vert; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<vert; j++) {
            matrix[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

You are defining the constructor of an explicitly specialized class, not an explicit specialization of the constructor. Similarly, avoid using `template<>` for the definition of other members:

```
int Matrix<int>::numEdges()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Also notice, that the programming practice of returning a `const` by value is dubious: rather use `int` than `const int`.